# URLField in django models allowing users to submit blank records, why?

Tags: python, database, url, django

This is what my `models.py` file looks like:

```
from django.db import models
class AccountModel(models.Model):
    url =  models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

The database is still allowing blank url fields to be submitted, what could be the problem?

I have deleted and synced my db several times and run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`

What could I be doing wrong?
Do I have to validate the field manually in my `views.py` perhaps?

I'm using django 1.8 and python 2.7.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same exact issue.  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills - this wasn't allowed before, right?

Comment: I just put a breakpoint in validators.URLValidator.__call__(), and it never gets called.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a programming question, and therefore should've been asked on [SO]. It's too late to migrate it now, but in the future please check that your questions are on-topic for the site you're posting them on.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for me was to set the requirement in `forms.py`.

```
from django import forms
from models import AccountModel

class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountModel
        fields = "__all__"
    url = forms.URLField(label='Url', required=True)
```

I realise this is no help to those not capturing data through a form :(